# I want to access the methods of a class I have reached using a String

Tags: java

```
Class.forName(gameGrid.getGameGridArray().get(0)[0]).newInstance();
```

Here's my class:

```
public class D {
   public D() {

}
   public void readText() {
      System.out.println("Yes");
} }
```

'newInstance()' method brings me constructor. But I dont want to access constructor.

I want to call readText() method of this class.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: maybe `YourClassName cls = xxxxx.newInstance(); cls.specificMethod()` ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Invoke an instance method reflectively, or a static method?

Comment: By 'access', do you mean call?

Comment: @tgdavies Yes, I want to call the methods of this class.

Comment: Instance methods or static methods?

Comment: @Sweeper Instance methods

Comment: Then you _need_ an instance of it don't you? Once you have an instance, you call `getMethod` to get a method, then call it with that instance.

Comment: I think you should explain a bit more about where the instances of the class come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to invoke a method, you need an object instance of the class.
Through reflection you can access the method you want to invoke:

```
Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(gameGrid.getGameGridArray().get(0)[0]);
Object objectInstance = aClass.newInstance();
Method method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod("nameOfMethod");
method.invoke(objectInstance);
```

Unless it is a static method, then you can invoke with null (credits to Ernest Kiwele).

```
Method method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod("nameOfMethod");
method.invoke(null);
```

Comment: What does exactly 'objectInstance' mean ?

Comment: If method is static, it can be invoked null, that may be useful to include in answer...

Comment: Thanks it worked but, if method is not static , How should I call it ?

Comment: @MertYanık  without reflection, when calling a none static method, it would be `Object objectInstance = new YourClass();  a.nameOfMethod();`. The `objectInstance` here is the same as the reflect version.